# Java. How to skip over an initialized variable?

Tags: java, if-statement, int

So im making a program and a different class refers to an int in a different class:

```
if (Doihavetools==0 && Stone.StoneCounter>=10 && Wood.WoodCounter>=50){
```

but in the other class, the int is initialized before the value is "++"ed

```
int WoodCounter;
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String action = e.getActionCommand();
    if (action.equals("Chop some wood")) {//ADD A .25 SECOND DELAY INBETWEEN CLICKS
        Random Rand = new Random();
        int W = Rand.nextInt(3) + 1;
        if(W==2){
            WoodCounter++;
        }
        Wood.setText("Click To Collect Wood : Wood:" + WoodCounter);
        System.out.println(WoodCounter);

    }
}
```

Is there a way so i can successfully initialize it and add to it at the same time? (i want to be able to continuously add to it)

Thanks in Advance,
Jack

Comment: Probably it's me, but I'm confused. Could you clarify your goals a bit more?

Comment: When i do the first if statement, the "woodcounter" always comes up with the value of zero, because java sees it initialized and then skips me adding to it. ask if you need more of an explanation

Comment: Unrelated to your question, in Java the convention is to make all variables start with lower case letters, types start with upper case letters, and constants be all capital letters. Adhering to this convention will help others read your code.

Comment: Yes, again speaking only for myself, I'll need more explanation. Also, these variables aren't static are they? If they are, they shouldn't be. As an aside, you will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter.

Comment: (To Hover, thanks for the suggestion, ill check it out) but putting that aside. the problem is that Java retrieves the value of "woodCounter" and doesn't see that i add to the value.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels2, I don't know if I've ever seen a field that should be static without also being final and immutable. Static variables make code harder to understand while simultaneously limiting reuse. The only exception I can think of is that it might make sense to have a static `SecureRandom` instance, but then again that could cause concurrency problems.

Comment: (Crude Explanation) if | = The variable, \ = the variable after being changed and ^ is what is trying to retrieve the variable.  basically ^ sees | and doesn't stick around to see it become \

Comment: @JeffWard This Is run over and over, the randomly generated # has nothing to do with it. it is just so that it only is add on occasion

Comment: I think I am confused like the others. Is your `WoodCounter` a member of a class, static, other?

Comment: WoodCounter is a int value that i am repeatedly adding to. and is being repeatedly being called from another class. so i might add to woodcounter until it is equal to 5, then i call it from another class and it is still equal to 0, as when it started.

Comment: @dfeuer: I think we are in agreement, that this code has the smell of static over-use.

Comment: @Everyone THEIR IS NO STATIC ANYTHING

Comment: @Wamlab The fact that your first line of code has `Wood.WoodCounter` in it *heavily* implies that `WoodCounter` is in fact a static variable, unless you named your instance of `Wood` with a capital letter... In which case, the confusion being experienced is entirely unsurprising.

Comment: @user3580294 when i declare "int WoodCounter;" in the code provided, that is inside of the Wood class. And that is the first and only time that variable is declared.

Comment: @Wamlab Then you named your instance `Wood` with a capital first letter?

Comment: @user3580294 Yeah, i totally forgot about the "naming convention"

Comment: @Wamlab Well no wonder everyone here thinks the instance is static... Naming conventions exist for a reason.

Comment: @Wamlab What do you want to initialize the variable to anyways? It's initialized to 0 when the class is created...

Comment: Naming conventions not only matter but in a snippet of code without all the surrounding context it takes 15 questions just to figure that out.

Comment: @Everyone Guys, i fixed it. Thanks for all the suggestions. (I just declared it globally) Thanks to explodingcreeperssss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is for the variable to hold it's value. Try making another variable, a boolean, and before you initialize it, make a check to see if you have already done so. Also, declare this boolean in the class where

```
if (Doihavetools==0 && Stone.StoneCounter>=10 && Wood.WoodCounter>=50){
```

is present, at the top. (make it public)

so... then you can

```
if(initialized == false)
{
    int WoodCounter;
    initialized = true;
}
```

Either that, or just use Wood.WoodCounter instead of declaring a new variable.

Comment: the declaration of woodCounter before the actionPreformed method is the first time woodCounter is delcared (that is inside the Wood class)

Comment: Then declare it globally?

Comment: Thats not the problem. the problem is that the place that WoodCounter is being called from is seeing "int WoodCounter;" and then just going with that and not waiting to see the value added to it

Comment: If you declared it globally, you would not have to wait for it to obtain a value, it already would have one, assuming the other class is called somewhere in the same class that WoodCounter is...

Comment: i would upvote if i could but i dont have the rep yet (my first post)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't declare a `woodCounter` variable unless you want to use it for something. Write `wood.woodCounter` to access the variable you seem to intend.